# I cannot send two emails with mailki

Tags: mailkit

I have a contact form on my web site, I want to send the client one email, and the second email goes to me I am baffled, all I can do is one, and tired everything, maybe you can help.

Here is my code thanks guys...:),

```
                var message = new MimeMessage();
                message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(name, EM));
                message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("DBT WEB", "tony@dbtweb.com"));
                message.Subject = string.Concat("DBTweb from ", " ", name);

                var builder = new BodyBuilder();

                var replaceLine = MSG.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");

                var Theyear = DateTime.Now.Year;

               builder.HtmlBody = string.Concat("Hi Tony this person sent you a message, the 
               persons name is <br /><br />", name, "<br /><br />The phone if any is 
               <strong>", PHnum, "</strong><br /><br />The city is <strong>", CIT, "</strong> 
               <br /><br />The State is <strong>", prov, "</strong><br /><br />The message is: 
               <br /><br />", replaceLine, "<br /><br />");

                message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

                var message1 = new MimeMessage();
                message1.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("DBT WEB", "tony@dbtweb.com"));
                message1.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(name, EM));
                message1.Subject = string.Concat("Thank you from DBT WEB ", " ", name);

                var builder1 = new BodyBuilder();

                builder1.TextBody = string.Concat(@"Thank you for starting the discusstion on 
                your new web site possabilities ", name,
                    " I will get back to you in a few days, in the mean time I have attatached 
                my reume for your review, all the best," + " Tony Trapp ");

                
           
                builder1.Attachments.Add(@"C:\ttrappresume5.docx");

                message1.Body = builder1.ToMessageBody();

                using (var emailClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
                {
                    // email to me
                    emailClient.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
                    emailClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                    emailClient.Connect("0.0.0.0", 25, false);
                    emailClient.Authenticate("tony@dbtweb.com", "T8sk?3o5"); // T8sk?3o5
                    emailClient.Send(message);
                    //emailClient.Send(message1);
                    emailClient.Disconnect(true);
                    return new JsonResult(name);
```

Comment: You have the second Send(message1) call commented out. That's why it's not sending it ;-)

Comment: I did that to see if I can get one , then it was uncommented it did go through that's  why I am baffled jstedfast

Comment: Now you are just confusing me. What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: I can't send two email one to me and one to the client, that's the problem. Once again thanks for your help...:)

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Is your computer melting down? Are aliens from outer space zapping the Ethernet cable when your code attempts to send the second message? What, exactly, is happening?